# Highcharts - Get container ID from barclick

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to get the container id of the chart when I click on a bar in the chart.  Basically the id of the nearest highcharts-container element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
        events:{
            click: function(){
                alert(this.chart.renderTo.id);
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        }
        }
    }
```

Edit:
If you want id of nearest parent element then do it with jquery like http://jsfiddle.net/asadsarwar89/dg3n7fhz/

Comment: Thanks...I was trying in within the bar point events with no success.